# Spring Boot uses incorrect config server url – http://localhost instead of http://config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-cloud-config-server

I have two modules in my project: config-server(spring-cloud-config-server) and service(spring-cloud-starter-config).

*service* **application.properties**:

```
server.port=0

spring.application.name=service

spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://config:8888
spring.cloud.config.username=root
spring.cloud.config.password=secret
```

*config-server* **application.properties**:

```
server.port=8888
spring.application.name=config
spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=classpath:/{application}/
spring.profiles.active=native
spring.security.user.name=root
spring.security.user.password=secret
```

**docker-compose.yml**:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  config:
    build:
      context: config-server
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
    networks:
      - test-network
    container_name: config
  service:
    build:
      context: service
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    restart: always
    networks:
      - test-network
    depends_on:
      - config
    container_name: service

networks:
  test-network:
    driver: bridge
```

If I run docker-compose, service will fail because it can't to access http://**localhost**:8888, but there is no localhost urls in my project at all.
As you see there is a *spring.config.import=optional:configserver:http://config:8888* in properties-file.
When I run service locally, it fails because http://config:8888 is unknown (as expected due to properties)

*Exception log on local run*:

```
2023-12-01T20:54:32.405+04:00  INFO 80254 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Fetching config from server at : http://config:8888
2023-12-01T20:54:32.405+04:00  INFO 80254 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Exception on Url - http://config:8888:org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://config:8888/service2/default": config. Will be trying the next url if available
2023-12-01T20:54:32.405+04:00  WARN 80254 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Could not locate PropertySource ([ConfigServerConfigDataResource@2f98635e uris = array<String>['http://config:8888'], optional = true, profiles = 'default']): I/O error on GET request for "http://config:8888/service2/default": config
```

*Exception log on docker-compose run*:

```
2023-12-01T16:31:31.641Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888
2023-12-01T16:31:31.642257888Z 2023-12-01T16:31:31.641Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Exception on Url - http://localhost:8888:org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/service/default": Connection refused. Will be trying the next url if available
2023-12-01T16:31:31.642333971Z 2023-12-01T16:31:31.642Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Could not locate PropertySource ([ConfigServerConfigDataResource@20140db9 uris = array<String>['http://root:secret@localhost:8888'], optional = true, profiles = 'default']): I/O error on GET request for "http://localhost:8888/service/default": Connection refused
```

Comment: since docker-compose and local run are different, make sure that the docker image is up to date, the docker container runs with the correct spring profiles etc. Everything looks imo correct, so the issue has to be somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

According to Loading comment, Deleting images is required. docker-compose doesn't rebuild images on each run